# Ошибка доступа при компиляции hadoop программы

Tags: unix, map-reduce, java, компиляция, linux

Попытался скомпилировать hadoop-программу с помощью команды

```
root@one:/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin# ./javac -classpath /export/hadoop-1.0.1/hadoop-core-1.0.1.jar;/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar -d /folder/classes /folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java
```

и получил в результате следуюшие сообщения

```
javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use a help for a list of possible options
bash: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar: Permission denied
```

и это происходит несмотря, что владельцем `/export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar` является `root`, на него установлены максимальные права, а файл `/folder/src/ParallelIndexation.java` действительно существует (это замечание насчет строки `javac: no source files`). Объясните, как устранить ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l /export/hadoop-1.0.1/log4j-1.2.17.jar` что кажет?

P.S. Нельзя работать под пользователем root! Это опасно. Используй `su`

P.P.S. Нельзя запускать компилятор находясь в системном каталоге: `/opt/jdk1.7.0_06/bin` - засунь javac в PATH и работай с `~/`

**Update**
Надо использовать ключ `-sourcepath` - должен показывать на каталог где лежат исходники

Answer (score 1):

@Barmaley уже выяснилось, что необходимо использовать `:` вместо `;` при разделении путей к `jar` файлам (см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108763/access-error-in-case-of-compilation-of-hadoop-of-the-program ). Но за желание помочь и высказанные советы спасибо.

Comment: @ivan89, а Вы не знали, что `;` в шелл разделяет команды?